# How to delete the file after a `return FileResponse(file_path)`

Tags: python, python-asyncio, fastapi, starlette

I'm using FastAPI to receive an image, process it and then return the image as a FileResponse.

But the returned file is a temporary one that need to be deleted after the endpoint return it.

```py
@app.post("/send")
async def send(imagem_base64: str = Form(...)):

    # Convert to a Pillow image
    image = base64_to_image(imagem_base64)

    temp_file = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix = '.jpeg')
    image.save(temp_file, dpi=(600, 600), format='JPEG', subsampling=0, quality=85)

    return FileResponse(temp_file)

    # I need to remove my file after return it
    os.remove(temp_file)
```

How can I delete the file after return it ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can delete a file in a [background task](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/), as it will run *after* the response is sent.

```
import os
import tempfile

from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse

from starlette.background import BackgroundTasks

app = FastAPI()


def remove_file(path: str) -> None:
    os.unlink(path)


@app.post("/send")
async def send(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    fd, path = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.txt')
    with os.fdopen(fd, 'w') as f:
        f.write('TEST\n')
    background_tasks.add_task(remove_file, path)
    return FileResponse(path)
```

Another approach is to use [dependency with yield](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/dependencies-with-yield/). The `finally` block code will be executed after the response is sent and even after all background tasks have been completed.

```
import os
import tempfile

from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse


app = FastAPI()


def create_temp_file():
    fd, path = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.txt')
    with os.fdopen(fd, 'w') as f:
        f.write('TEST\n')
    try:
        yield path
    finally:
        os.unlink(path)


@app.post("/send")
async def send(file_path=Depends(create_temp_file)):
    return FileResponse(file_path)
```

*Note*: [mkstemp()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp) returns a tuple with a file descriptor and a path.

Comment: I tried the second approach, with the dependency, but the file is deleted too soon in the flow and the response fails with `RuntimeError: File at path ... does not exist.`.

Answer (score 17):

You can pass the cleanup task as a parameter of `FileResponse`:

```py
from starlette.background import BackgroundTask

# ...

def cleanup():
    os.remove(temp_file)

return FileResponse(
    temp_file,
    background=BackgroundTask(cleanup),
)
```

#### UPDATE 12-08-2022

If someone is generating the filename dynamically, then one may pass the parameters to the background task, e.g., as follows

```
return FileResponse(
    temp_file,
    background=BackgroundTask(cleanup, file_path),
)
```

The `cleanup` function then needs to be adapted to accept a parameter, which will be the filename, and call the `os.remove` function with the filename as parameter instead of the global variable

Comment: Even simpler: you can use `background=BackgroundTask(os.remove, temp_file)`. `os.remove` is already a callable function you can pass to BackgroundTask, you don't need to wrap it into another one.

Comment: The problem with BackgroundTasks is that in case of any exception, they are not run.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to send `FileResponse` with a background task attached that deletes the file or folder.

[click here](https://www.starlette.io/background/) for more info

The background task will run after the response has been served, so it can safely delete the file/folder.

```py
# ... other important imports
from starlette.background import BackgroundTasks

@app.post("/send")
async def send(imagem_base64: str = Form(...), bg_tasks: BackgroundTasks):

    # Convert to a Pillow image
    image = base64_to_image(imagem_base64)

    temp_file = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix = '.jpeg')
    image.save(temp_file, dpi=(600, 600), format='JPEG', subsampling=0, quality=85)


    bg_tasks.add_task(os.remove, temp_file)
 
   return FileResponse(
    temp_file,
    background=bg_tasks
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

To ensure the temporary file is deleted after the request, also when the request fails unexpectedly mid-flight, using FastAPI's [Dependency Injection](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/) system is recommended:

```py
import os
from typing import Annotated

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse

app = FastAPI()


async def temp_path():
    """Create (and finally delete) a temporary file in a safe and non-blocking fashion."""
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    _, path = await loop.run_in_executor(None, tempfile.mkstemp)
    try:
        yield path
    finally:
        await loop.run_in_executor(None, os.unlink, path)


@app.get("/test")
async def test(
    ...,
    temp_path_1: Annotated[str, Depends(temp_path, use_cache=False)],
    temp_path_2: Annotated[str, Depends(temp_path, use_cache=False)],
):
    assert temp_path_1 != temp_path_2, "2 unique files due to use_cache=False"

    if "x" in temp_path_1:
        raise RuntimeError("Unexpected internal server error still deletes the files")

    return FileResponse(
        temp_path_1,
        media_type="video/mp4",
        filename="video_out.mp4",
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work also

```
import tempfile
from fastapi import FileResponse


class TempFileResponse(FileResponse):
    def __init__(self, prefix, **params) -> None:
        self.temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(prefix=prefix)
        super().__init__(path=self.temp_file.name, **params)

    def __del__(self):
        # This will delete the file
        self.temp_file.close()


@router.get("/produce-data", response_class=FileResponse)
async def produce() -> FileResponse:
    file_name = "some_file_data.txt"
    logger.info(f"Downloading data as {file_name}")
    response_file = TempFileResponse(prefix="some_file_", filename=file_name)
    with open(response_file.temp_file.name, "w") as f:
        f.write("Hello, world!")
    return response_file
```